# PPA repository error 18.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Fairly new to ubuntu and every command I run gives me this error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/932Mt.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xenial repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you did the upgrade to 18.10, in some cases, it changed working repository locations, to locations looking for repositories compatible with `cosmic`. Not all repositories have `cosmic` compatible files, hence the error.

For each error, go to the `http://` location, like:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/

and then click on the `dists` link, and view what the latest supported Ubuntu version is listed... in this example, it would be `xenial` (not `cosmic`).

Open the `Software & Updates` app, go to the `Other Software` tab, and change the `Wine` properties from `cosmic` to `xenial`. When you've made all of the changes, close the window, and click the `Reload` button to update the software databases.

**Update #1:**

In `terminal`...

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d      # change directory
grep -i nvidia *.list           # find out which filename to edit
more nvidia.list                # view the correct found fileneme
# check the http web site as per my earlier instructions and
# determine the most recent Ubuntu version (if it isn't cosmic)
sudo pico nvidia.list           # put in the proper found filename to edit
sudo apt-get update             # you may have errors here if you didn't fix the other errors
sudo apt-get install dkms nvidia-dkms-390 nvidia-utils-390 # install
reboot                          # reboot the computer
```

Comment: thanks for the help brother.

Also if you can help me with setting up nvidia drivers, would be great. I already installed the 390 driver for my gt 820m which it supports but I am not sure how to switch to nvidia card while I run a game.

Comment: @Dominator I don't know much about switching video cards. I know there's a CLI command to do it, but there must be something in the GUI to do it too. Go ahead and start a new question and see if you can get more help. Cheers.

Comment: Hey is it possible to change that through terminal (cosmic to xenial). I messed up with nvidia and I cant install it again from terminal due to it being cosmic ppa. Can't see the gui, black screen.

Comment: Yes, use the terminal, and ... oh, let me just update my answer... much more readable... give me a few minutes...

Comment: How to do it from terminal, can you tell me command please